# FFmpeg output to an array without saving to file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Is there a way for ffmpy or FFmpeg to output images to an array without writing to a file?

I'm using

`ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4 -r 1/1 ./outputs/$filename-%03d.jpg`

But this outputs the result into files, I want to convert a video to an array of images, and save it as binary objects in cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module and capture output to stdout.

Your command would look like:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4 -r 1/1 pipe:1
```